# Positioning input placeholder with icon in center

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic application using [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#bar-inputs) ionic component.

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
  <button class="button button-clear">
    Cancel
  </button>
</div>
```

I am able to center the placeholder using this css. However, only the text placeholder is being center. My intention is to make both the ionic search icon and the placeholder to be center as a whole as the picture below.

Note: There should be no assumption of the length of the placeholder text. eg: hard-code pixel to the left and right based on text length.

[image]

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting the icon element with a pseudo-element:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
  content:'\1F50D';
  padding-right: .2em;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-moz-placeholder::before {
  content:'\1F50D';
  padding-right: .2em;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7yxdfewq/